# How to get the key behind the content of the visible row in a tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

What I'm trying to do is:

My tableview sources a post from firebase database, when other users see the post, I want to get the key of the post they are currently viewing. I want to store this key as a string that I can use elsewhere.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "post")
    let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: posts[indexPath.row].postUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "SymboleBLANC3x-1.jpg"))
    return cell!
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.frame.size.height
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadPosts()
}

var posts = [Post]()
func loadPosts() {
    Database.database().reference().child("posts").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]{
            let url = dict["postUrl"] as? String
            let rank = dict["rank"] as? Int
            let post = Post(urlString: url!, rankNumber: rank ?? 0)
            self.posts.append(post)
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last visible index from below code and on the basis of that you can fetch the content from your main array.

```
let visibleArray = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
let indexPath = visibleArray?.value(forKeyPath: "@max.self") as? IndexPath
```

Comment: I'm no trying to get the index, but the key of the content from firebase. Knowing that the array on firebase can me modified while the user has downloaded a less up to date version of the array, I still want to retrieve the key of the post (i.e the index of the array on firebase and the downloaded array on the client can be different).